# A single site for reporting unknown viruses

Tags: malware, spam

I have just received an email with an unknown virus. I happily passed through my scanners. I have checked it's still unknown to all of 4 anti-viruses I have an access to.

I have already reported it to ClamAV and to Kaspersky but I when I tried to report it to other systems I quickly gave up. Some of them require registering, some require reporting as an encrypted email attachment. It's difficult to put a sample into over a dozen of antiviral systems.

Is there a single service for reporting virus samples?

Answer (score 4):

You have a hand full of of Virus checking online services:

1. [Virus total](http://www.virustotal.com)
2. [Herdprotect](http://herdprotect.com)
3. [Meta scan](https://www.metascan-online.com/)
4. [Jotti's Malware scanner](http://virusscan.jotti.org/)
5. [Threatexpert](http://www.threatexpert.com/submit.aspx)
6. [Uploadmalware](http://www.uploadmalware.com/)
7. [Web of Trust](https://www.mywot.com/wiki/Malware_submission)

Most of them have connection with Security product vendors and may forward your samples upon request by the vendors.

Alternatively, you can directly email each vendor: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-report-malware-or-false-positives-multiple-antivirus-vendors.htm